# Symfony 2.7.7 - Form Collection "Notice: Undefined index: pageId"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

Trying to generate a form in which it will be a collection of Contents, but unfortunately bereave her mistake and do not know how we recover.

**Gives me the error**

> Notice: Undefined index: pageId
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Page Entity:

```
class Page
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "PageContent", mappedBy = "pageId")
     */
    private $content;
}
```

PageContent Entity:

```
class PageContent
{
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Page", inversedBy = "page_content")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "page_id", referencedColumnName = "id", onDelete = "SET NULL")
     */
    private $page;
    private $name;
}
```

EditPageContentsType :

```
<?php
namespace Eteam\SettingsBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class EditPageContentsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'EditPageContents';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('pageContentMap')
            ->add('content', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new PageContentType(),
                'options'  => array(
                    'required'  => false
                ),
                'allow_add' => true
            ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Eteam\PageBundle\Entity\Page',
        ));
    }
}
```

PageContentType:

```
<?php
namespace Eteam\SettingsBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PageContentType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pageContent';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Test'
            ))
            ->add('content')
            ->add('type')
            ->add('pageId');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Eteam\PageBundle\Entity\PageContent',
        ));
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Because of this I'm a beginner here and in Synfony 2, please do not click negatives. Thanks.

---

P.S.

If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your annotations are wrong.

Page should be:

```
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "PageContent", mappedBy = "page")
```

PageContent should be:

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Page", inversedBy = "content")
```

mappedBy and inversedBy by are directly related to the property names of the object for the relations and have to be the same.

Secondly as PageContent is a child of Page, you don't need pageId in your PageContentType. This is a better way to do things.

In EditPageContentsType, add the option `'by_reference' => false` [see here for why](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference)

Then change your addContent() method in Page

```
public function addContent(PageContent $pageContent)
{
    $pageContent->setPage($this);

    $this->content->add($pageContent);
}
```

Similar to the addTag example down a little way [in this document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype)

This allows you to easily associate Page with PageContent entities. I recommend having a good read of the [forms documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) as you will see this sort of thing a lot.

Comment: **Thank you very much.**  
I still have one question on  this is already a form.  PageContent consists of:  name  type  content  In the form of editing is to be only content, the 'name' is the name of a 'type' input this type of input such 'text' or 'textarea'.  And here my question: how to inject this information to form?

Comment: Why do you need to store the content type? If it is at time of content creation you could make type a select field. Also, If my original answer helped you please mark it useful.

Comment: Thanks.
When I have enough reputation points for sure I will.

Comment: You see this point is that these fields are not editable, only the content and the type and name is for information only and as the setting fields in the form.    
for example:
name: Title
type: text
content: a place to fill,
name: Article
type: textarea
content: a place to fill,
and so it looks.
If you have an idea that I will be super-grateful because I no longer have totally no idea how it skipped.